# What do you call a giant aquarium?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a giant aquarium? I found the term aquatic museum, but I thought there was a single word for this. I can't remember what it was though.

Answer (score 1):

Oceanarium

> a large seawater aquarium in which marine animals are kept for study and public exhibit. (Google dictionary)

Check this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarium

Comment: And here I thought the word was giant aquarium.